# P-curve analysis for meta-analysis of diagnostic accuracy study

Tags: meta-analysis, publication-bias, diagnosis

I tried to do a meta-analysis of diagnostic accuracy study. I found out that I have a publication bias based on the Deek's regression test. Thus, I want to supplement my analysis with P-curve analysis which I read from [here](https://bookdown.org/MathiasHarrer/Doing_Meta_Analysis_in_R/pub-bias.html#p-curve). The author used the P-curve analysis with interventional studies.

I have tried to the P-curve analysis with a diagnostics odds ratio (DOR) model, however I am quite doubtful whether the P-curve analysis is appropriate in this meta-analysis.

I tried to find any example or paper that uses P-curve analysis with meta-analysis of diagnostic accuracy study, I have found none so far. Any opinion is appreciated.

Thanks